# Pegar dados do banco de dados 1 e passar para o banco de dados 2

Tags: php

Tenho um banco de dados em um host e queria passar dados para o banco de dados de outro host, mais o host não aceita conexão externa, como eu posso fazer isso? Alguém teria alguma sugestão? usando PHP e MYSQL

Comment: Faz o php e roda dentro do servidor, usa PDO faz duas conexoes da o select captura os valores e da o insert no outro banco

Comment: A forma mais simples é entrar nos servidor por um phpMyAdmin, exportar em um e importar no outro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você tiver acesso ao PHPMyAdmin é mais facil simplesmente vai em exportar e depois em importar no novo destino.

Se você tiver acesso somente a linha de comando você pode usar o mysqldump algo como:
Exportando:

```
mysqldump -u root-p database1 > database1.sql
```

Importando:

```
mysql -u root-p database2 < database1.sql
```

> Lembre-se de alterar os dados para conexão

fonte: [Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407349/how-to-export-and-import-a-sql-file-from-command-line)